# What is the opposite to "only marks" option in PGFPlots?

Tags: pgfplots, options

For some application I generate a bunch of plots automatically from a script, that means that sometimes I issue contradictory options to pgfplots objects because one is the default (within the script), for example

```
\addplot[red, ...bla..., blue]{ ... }
\addplot[mark=*, ...bla..., mark=+]{ ... }
```

Fortunately, pgfplots overwrites previous settings in order. In this occasion however, the default is "only marks" (which makes the plot not to have joining lines),

**What would be option to *overwrite* "only marks"?**

For example

```
\addplot[only marks, ...bla..., draw_lines_please]{ ... }
```

and makes the plot actually have joining lines by overwriting the first "only marks". (draw_lines_please replaces the option that I am looking for). (If there is one) **What is the name of such option?**

(I guess the question also applies in the case where only marks is the global pgfplots option, but the question is specific for the case above)

Comment: This overriding property of the options does not apply to all possible keys. You can use the `no markers` option to get only the curves however it seems that `only marks` wins over it. Try for example `\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[no markers] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}` with and without `only marks`

Comment: Yes. But "no markers" is *not* the opposite to "only marks", the opposite to "only marks" has nothing to do with markers but it is something that positively says to draw lines between points (whether the points are visible or not).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To reactivate drawing lines between the coordinates, use the key `sharp plot` (which is the standard plot type):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend entries={only marks,{only marks, sharp plot}},
    legend pos=outer north east,
    mark=*
]
\addplot [cyan, only marks] {rnd};
\addplot [orange, only marks, sharp plot] {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: great, it is documented in section "5.2.1 Linear Plots", easy to find once you know what to look for.