# How do I make a TikZ/pgfplots scatter plot without lines between points

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am attempting to make a scatter plot from a table of data. I seem to have almost succeeded, but there are lines between the points. I do not want this to happen, but I can't figure out how to remove them. My current code is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:3]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$T_{\text{meas}}$}, ylabel={$T_{\text{cal}}$}]
\addplot[scatter, scatter src=\thisrow{class},
      error bars/.cd, y dir=both, x dir=both, y explicit, x explicit, error bar style={color=mapped color}]
      table[x=x,y=y,x error=xerr,y error=yerr] {
    x       xerr    y        yerr       class
    0.98521 0.00031 1        0.000001   0
    0.49238 0.00044 0.5      0.00000025 0
    1.09346 0.00032 1.111111 0.0000012  0
    1.23021 0.00078 1.25     0.0000016  0
    1.40567 0.00047 1.428571 0.000002   0
    1.63971 0.00064 1.666667 0.0000028  0
    1.96753 0.00063 2        0.000004   0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This creates a plot that looks like this
[image: scatter plot with lines]

but I want it to look like this

[image: scatter plot without lines]

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to add the `only marks` option to the `\addplot`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:3]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$T_{\text{meas}}$}, ylabel={$T_{\text{cal}}$}]
\addplot[scatter, only marks, scatter src=\thisrow{class},
      error bars/.cd, y dir=both, x dir=both, y explicit, x explicit, error bar style={color=mapped color}]
      table[x=x,y=y,x error=xerr,y error=yerr] {
    x       xerr    y        yerr       class
    0.98521 0.00031 1        0.000001   0
    0.49238 0.00044 0.5      0.00000025 0
    1.09346 0.00032 1.111111 0.0000012  0
    1.23021 0.00078 1.25     0.0000016  0
    1.40567 0.00047 1.428571 0.000002   0
    1.63971 0.00064 1.666667 0.0000028  0
    1.96753 0.00063 2        0.000004   0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: and its opposite appears to be ``sharp plot``: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49590/what-is-the-opposite-to-only-marks-option-in-pgfplots